# Regex for obtaining value for specific key in xml file

Tags: regex, shell, perl, sed

I need to get the value for the key "CFBundleShortVersionString" using a regular expression.I have searched a lot but i did not find any regular expression that gets the value which is in next line.So can any one please help me with a regular expression that fetches the value or if there is any another way in which i can get the value for the specific key.Please let me know.

```
<dict>
        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>tel</string>
            <string>itms-beta</string>
            <string>itms-apps</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Hire ASAP</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.4.2</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression? That's not a good idea. Use a parser instead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew one which work for me that accept the answer

Comment: How do you plan to extract that value? What are the rules?

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am ok with a regex or any other method my requirement is I have to write value user has input to that particular key I mean I have replace the value for that key with user input value.

Comment: The problem is we do not know how to find that key. If a human does not know that, how can you code that so that a machine could?

Comment: Too bad this got closed: this is just an [tag:xpath] exercise => `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//dict/key[text() = "CFBundleDisplayName"]/following-sibling::string[1]' -n file.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Parsing XML with a regex is a terrible idea. Please don't do that.

The equivalent of regexes for XML is called XPath. I use [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) for running XPath queries against XML documents.

Something like this does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $key = 'CFBundleDisplayName';
my $xml = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);

# XPath expression.
# Look for a "string" node where the first
# preceding sibling "key" node has text that
# is the key you are looking for and return the
# text of the node you've found.

my $xpath = "//string[preceding-sibling::key[position()=1][text()='$key']]/text()";

say "XPath: $xpath";

for ($dom->findnodes($xpath)) {
  say $_->to_literal;
}

__DATA__
<dict>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>itms-beta</string>
    <string>itms-apps</string>
  </array>
  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>Hire ASAP</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.4.2</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: ok this is to get the value if I want to rewrite the key with a new value how can i do that

Comment: @ManojCK: I put the key in a variable in order to make it as easy as possible to change it. You could even set it from user input.

Comment: I don't want to change the key I want to replace the value which is present for that key

Comment: @ManojCK: Ok. Well, that requirement wasn't in your original question (and this question has been closed), so you should probably ask that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the language I made it using the *re* module from the Python's library. Here there is a quick solution to your problem:

`version = re.findall(r"CFBundleShortVersionString.*\n.*<string>(.+)</string>", xml_file)`

**EDIT**: since you asked for a shell solution simply put that line in a *.py* script and pass the XML file as argument.